# javascript mongoose pass message between two schema hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How can I pass message between two schema hooks so that when the pre or post of the inner schema is completed a message can be passed 
back to the outer schema about the

Schema1.js

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        full_name           : String,
        other_name          : String,
        last_name           : String,
        email               : String
        });

userSchema.pre('save', function (){
    //obtain values from form field
    var formField1 = employmentDate;
    var formField2 = responsibility;

    const employmentObject = this.model('employment-detail');   
    employmentObjectins = new employmentObject({
                    'employment_date': formField1,
                    'responsibility' :formField2
                });

    employmentObjectins.save(function (err, result){
        recieve message from schema's operation

    });
});
```

Schema2.js

```
var employmentSchem = mongoose.Schema({
            employment_date : String,
            responsibility  : String
            })

employmentSchem.post('save', function(err, result){
    if(err){
        return 'error in saving'//
    }
    else{
        return 'properly saved';//this would be returned back to user schema
    }
});
```